# Is there a single word for a mistaken intention due to a situation

Tags: single-word-requests

This has bugged me for a number of years and the English language is full of less often or rarely used words so I thought I'd finally ask this question.

Take the a situation where an artist mistakenly smears paint across a canvas while hanging it and leaves.  He means to come back and completely paint over the mistake, but someone walks by and notices it and attributes it to genius.  The artist is surprised at this, but doesn't correct the guest and accepts the praise.

Is there a word for accepting credit for an unintended action?

Another example would be a person who says something and it's considered hilarious by everyone around them.  They didn't mean it that way, but they accept the credit for the wit without correcting the audience.

This has happened often enough in my life that it really bugs me that I haven't found a single descriptive word meant for this type of situation.  As you can tell from the number of words I'm using to describe this, there's an obvious need for a single word in these cases.

Comment: The event itself could be called a "fortuitous accident".  But I don't know a word for the whole "make a fortuitous accident, get praised for it, and bluff your way through" situation.

Comment: **op·por·tun·ism** _n._:  the art, policy, or practice of taking advantage of opportunities or circumstances, especially with little regard for principles or ultimate consequences [M-W Unabridged]

Comment: Type the word *serendipitous* into the search box in the upper right of your screen, and see if results indicate that the word is of use to you.

Comment: Nassin Taleb has anticipated your need and repurposed the "black swan" idiom to suit. Taleb's black swan is basically when some seeming minor event, or random event turns out to be a game-changer. https://www.amazon.com/Black-Swan-Improbable-Robustness-Fragility/dp/081297381X. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory

Answer (score 1):

***Cash in*** comes to my mind. I know it is mostly used in financial contexts, but it might work well in the situations you mention.

> According to [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cash_in), ***to cash in*** means to take advantage or
>   exploit a situation. (Check the list of synonyms.)

'To a certain extent, he's cashing in on the latest literary fad.'

> Another definition found [here](https://www.wordnik.com/words/cash%20in) reads: "To profit from; to use an opportunity
>   to maximum advantage, especially financially."

***Opportunism*** is also a good fit, as *Gnawme* suggests.